# Backpropagation (through time) code in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, backpropagation

Where can I find the backpropagation (through time) code in Tensorflow (python API)? Or are other algorithms used?

For example, when I create a LSTM net.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All backpropagation in TensorFlow is implemented by automatically differentiating the operations in the forward pass of the network, and adding explicit operations for computing the gradient at each point in the network. The general implementation can be found in [`tf.gradients()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e1c017624fd6bd8562c1da27e0014b32f389b524/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py#L307), but the particular version used depends on how your LSTM is implemented:

- If the LSTM is implemented as an unrolled loop for a finite number of timesteps, the usual approach is truncated backpropagation through time, which uses the algorithm in `tf.gradients()` to build an unrolled backpropagation loop in the opposite direction.
- If the LSTM is implemented as a `tf.while_loop()`, it uses additional support for differentiating loops in [`control_flow_grad.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_grad.py).

Comment: Please have  a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/66185202/14337775 and give you opinion

Comment: Is there a simple way to make tensorflow do truncated BPTT and determine the number of steps? Or do I necessarily have to build the unrolled network manually?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it but this might work:

Since RNNs can be trained just like feed forward nets, the code is very similar.
This is how you train a feed forward net: (X is the input)

```
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(error)

# Session
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for i in range(epochs):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={X: [[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]], labels: [[0], [1], [1], [0]]})
```

The only difference in back propagation through time is that **every epoch now has a nested time loop**.

This is the code to train a simple rnn:

```
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(error)

time_series = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
for i in range(number_of_epochs):
    for j in range(len(time_series) - 1):
        curr_X = time_series[j+1]
        curr_prev = time_series[j]
        lbs = curr_prev
        sess.run(train, feed_dict={X: [[curr_X]], prev_val: [[curr_prev]], labels: [[lbs]]})
```

In this code the rnn learns a time series with alternative 1s and 0s.